# onclick on spiderweb chart open new one for details

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I want to do something like this: http://tutsnare.com/onclick-open-new-chart-highcharts/ on click on a chart I get details displayed in another spiderweb chart but when I tried the example in the link with spiderweb chart it didn't work any help please?

here is my code:

```
$scope.configChart = {
  options: {
    chart: {
      polar: true,
      type: 'line'
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Dimensions result',
    x: -80
  },

  pane: {
    size: '80%'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
  },

  yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 70,
    layout: 'vertical'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Average',
    data: [],
  }]

};
```

the html :

```
<highchart id="container" config="configChart" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></highchart>
```

::: UPDATE :::

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Here's a live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vu96fr9h/2/

---

First thing, your `series` does not contain data. for this example, i initialized it with the following:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Average',
  data: [{
    id: "point-1",
    x: 1,
    y: 49.9
  }, {

    id: "point-2",
    x: 2,
    y: 71.5
  }, {

...
```

Next, you can set up a click event on a point by extending your `chartConfig` object like so:

```
options: {
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          point: {
            events: {
              click: function(e) {
                var point = {
                  x: this.x,
                  y: this.y,
                  id: this.id
                }

                $scope.$apply(function() {
                  $scope.selectedPoint = point;
                });
              }
            }
          },
          marker: {
            lineWidth: 1
          }
        }
      },

      ...
```

The click will store the point metadata in `$scope.selectedPoint`. you can add a `$scope.$watch` to get a notification when it changes:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedPoint', function(newValue) {

    // Here you can fetch more info about this point from the server 
    console.log(newValue);

});
```

The view will display what you want based on `$scope.selectedPoint`. it may be a secondary graph or plain metadata as text.

[image]

Comment: yes it's worked perfectly, there is any why to intercept the click on the title "gouvernance des achats" for example?

Comment: ok i see your updated post. would you please fork my jsfiddle and fill it with your data so i could give it a try?